# Create new columns based on 2 columns

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, apply

So I have this kind of table **df**

| Id | Type | QTY | unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | B | 10 | 2 |
| 3 | C | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | A | 10 | 4 |
| 3 | B | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | C | 10 | 6 |

I want to create this data frame **df2**

| Id | A_QTY | A_unit | B_QTY | B_unit | C_QTY | C_unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 6 |
| 2 | 10 | 4 | 10 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 3 |

This means that I want to create a new column for every "Type's" "QTY" and "unit" for each "Id". I was thinking to use a loop to first create a new column for each Type, to get something like this :

| Id | Type | QTY | unit | A_QTY | A_unit | B_QTY | B_unit | C_QTY | C_unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 5 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | B | 10 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | C | 5 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | A | 10 | 4 | 10 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | B | 5 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | C | 10 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 6 |

, and then group_by() to agregate them resulting in df2. But I get stuck when it comes to creating the new columns. I have tried the for loop but my level on R is still not that great yet. I can't manage to create new columns from those existing columns...

I'll appreciate any suggestions you have for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pivot_wider` from the `tidyr` package:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Type",            # Columns to get the names from
              values_from = c("QTY", "unit"), # Columns to get the values from
              names_glue = "{Type}_{.value}", # Column naming
              values_fill = 0,                # Fill NAs with 0 
              names_vary = "slowest")         # To get the right column ordering
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 7
     Id A_QTY A_unit B_QTY B_unit C_QTY C_unit
  <int> <int>  <int> <int>  <int> <int>  <int>
1     1     5      1     0      0    10      6
2     2    10      4    10      2     0      0
3     3     0      0     5      5     5      3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Id, Type)) %>% 
  mutate(name = str_c(Type, name, sep = "_")) %>% 
  select(-Type) %>%  
  pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "value", values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 3 × 7
     Id A_QTY A_unit B_QTY B_unit C_QTY C_unit
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     5      1     0      0    10      6
2     2    10      4    10      2     0      0
3     3     0      0     5      5     5      3
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I believe Mael's answer is a little simpler for renaming the columns.